# Break down dataframe values and sum

Tags: python, dataframe, sum

I want to break down dataframe rows' values by space and sum them. However, I stuck in the middle of it.

The data:

```
mydf
words              number   labels
travel abroad     1        Not_Zero
abroad holiday    0        Zero
holiday vacation  2        Not_Zero
```

Step 1: break down the 'words' column by space:
this will give me a list of individual words:

```
travel holiday vacation
```

Step 2: Sum same individual word's number column, and keep the labels column.

Step 3: If an individual word is labeled as both `Zero` and `Not_Zero`, use `Not_Zero`

```
words    number    labels
travel   1         Not_Zero
abroad   1         Not_Zero
holiday  2         Not_Zero
vacation 2         Not_Zero
```

So far I've done step 1 and 2, split words by space and sum them

```
def cutKeyAndCount(pRow):
    split= pRow['words'].split(' ')
    num = int(pRow['number'])
    for l in split:
        if len(df) > 0 and len(df.loc[df['key'] == l]):
            temp =  int(df.loc[df['key'] == l]['count']) + application
            df.loc[df['key'] == l,'count']= temp
        else:
            df.loc[len(df)] = [l,num]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['key','count'])
for i in range(0,len(mydf)):
    cutKeyAndCount(mydf.iloc[i])
```

However, I don't know how to do step 3, please can anyone give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit difficult, since the code you're showing doesn't work for me (application is undefined), but would the following work?

```
import numpy as np
df['counts'] = df['counts'].astype(int)
df['labels'] = np.where(df['counts'] == 0, 'Zero', 'Not_Zero')
```